# Use [id class] as a pointer

Tags: ios, class

I'm maybe trying to do something wrong, but it would help to make my code simple.

I have some class, to have the same function.
To avoid a long if, else if with `isKindOfClass`, I want to do something like that :

```
[(([myClassVar class] *) myClassVar) myFunction];
```

It can crash if `myClassVar` doesn't have myFunction but if I do the if, else if method, it would just not crash but just write an error in the last else case.

Someone have an idea how to do it ?

Thanks in advance,
Damien

**Edit :**
Answered by SamFisher, my code would be :

```
if( [myClassVar respondsToSelector:@selector(myFunction) )
    [myClassVar performSelector:@selector(myFunction)];
```

Comment: static typing to a dynamic code?

Comment: what are you trying to do here your statement is same as `[myClass myFunction];`

Comment: ([myClassVar class] *) myClassVar ?= myClassVar?

Comment: So, are you looking to slam everything to a single line?

Comment: yeah it's the same as `[myClassVar class]` will return the class of the `myClassVar' it look like some thing this `(MyClass*) myClassVar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't u use respondsToSelector: and then performSelector: ?

Comment: Very good. I know the respondsToSelector, but not the performSelector. That's perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

A more objective-c approach is to check if the instance supports the selector. If yes, call it.

For example,

```
if ( [myClassVar respondsToSelector:@selector(myFunction:)] ) {
    [myClassVar myFunction];
}
```

Comment: `[myClassVar myFunction];` wont execute without proper typecasting.

Comment: @samfisher I don't think so. You can write a simple command line app to try it out.

Comment: It was my first guess too, as I know `respondsToSelector`. But if myClassVar as the type of mother class, without myFunction, he won't compile as it will think that won't work. You really need to use `performSelector` to do it.

Comment: @user1511646 Fair enough. I was assuming myClassVar is declared to be of type 'id'